# Getting the apache kafka broker metrics using java jmx

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx, metrics

I am working on getting apache kafka metrics and store it in mysql database. At first I studied on JMX from oracle site but it has contents like developing a MBean and registering it in MBeanserver and viewing it in JConsole. But I have seen kafka MBeans in JConsole on starting kafka and zookeeper server without developing any MBeans for kafka. So, I got confusion whether I have to create a separate MBean for kafka or I can use/gather the MBeans that are already available on the kafka server. I studied that kafka exposes its metrics for monitoring and I configured the **JMX_PORT** in **kafka-run-class.sh** and in **kafka-server-start.sh** to port 9999.

kafka-server-start.sh

```
exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS kafka.Kafka "$@"
export JMX_PORT=9999
```

kafka-run-class.sh

```
if [ -z "$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS" ]; then
 KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
fi
if [  $JMX_PORT ]; then
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT "
fi
```

I applied jmx port like above and also on starting the server in CLI, I gave **JMX_PORT=9999 ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties** and using the program below I just tried to access one of the kafka broker metrics.

Server.java

```
package server.kafka.metrics;
import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try{
            System.out.println("Connection to JMX kafka...");
            JMXServiceURL url=new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:9999/jmxrmi");
            JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url,null);
            MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

            ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("kafka.server:type=ReplicaManager,name=UnderMinIsrPartitionCount");

            MBeanInfo info= mbsc.getMBeanInfo(mbeanName);
            MBeanAttributeInfo[] attribute=info.getAttributes();
            for(MBeanAttributeInfo attr : attribute){
                System.out.println(attr.getDescription()+" "+mbsc.getAttributes(mbeanName, new String[]{attr.getName()}));
            }
            jmxc.close();
         }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
         }
    }
 }
```

on executing this program I got error like this

```
Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:    javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: (Connection refused)]
```

The program above was taken reference from lot of jmx program for getting server metrics and I didn't even know the method was right or wrong so that I didn't add mysql database information for data appending in the program. I have used Promethus and Grafana but now I just want to collect those metrics manually through the program to save data in mysql database. If there is any mistakes in above method please give some suggestions or guidance to correct it.

Comment: You should not edit the scripts. You need to `export` **before** running them. I suggest you stick to Prometheus + its JMX exporter. You can still use the JMX exporter HTTP endpoint to scrape data into mysql if you really wanted

Comment: port 1099 is one I last tried to connect through JMX and I forgot to change it in the code here my mistake, sir. But in case of prometheus I can't able to understand how the MBean collection is happening so I have been trying to work on getting kafka broker metrics programmatically. Is this possible, sir?

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel. The Prometheus JMX Exporter is programmatic, as well - https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/collector/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JmxCollector.java#L531

Comment: But sorry sir, I am in need of building this program. So it will be helpful if any solution is suggested. I have found an api called 'org.apache.kafka.common.metrics', is this api can fetch metrics, sir?

Comment: You said in your question you were already using Prometheus, though, so why not use it still?

Comment: Yeah, I was in search for some program examples related to this kafka broker metrics collection, at that time I have seen prometheus but came to know its just an application which does the thing, I wanted to do programmatically and I don't want to use that application because my intention was not only the result but also I want to study how this works and I want to develop a program specifically for broker metric collection, sir.

Comment: As written, you code works when I run it, and prints `Attribute exposed for management [Value = 0]` so there is something wrong with how you exported the `JMX_PORT` variable. Again, you should not edit the shell scripts, so revert any changes you did make

Comment: Sir, can you please say how to export JMX_PORT variable properly. I have added JMX_PORT in kafka-server-start.sh and I have started my zookeeper server ''bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties'' and kafka server ''JMX_PORT=9999 ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties'' and after that I run this program in intellij ide as java program. Is these steps right one?

Comment: You need to `export`, not set in the same line. `export JMX_PORT=9999; kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`, after starting zookeeper (semi-colon, or separate line) then run your code in IntelliJ

Comment: Yes sir its working and I have been using incase of saving in database, I am storing the metrics in a text file and saving it in database. Is this method a good one?

Comment: Not really. You can write directly to the database instead of a file

Comment: Yes sir, but in case of directly adding it to the database table, my data was taking the table entirely and after 1000 rows my new data isn't appending after that i.e. from 1001, so adding it as a file may save some space in table, right?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, but no. If you're running an update/insert with timestamp, then you can append data for as long as you want until you fill your hard drive

Comment: Yes sir, I have found that just now. I am using mysql workbench and using the fetch rows option I am able to see all the logs till date and incase of metrics, I got different number of attributes like one mbean has five attributes and another one just has a single attribute and each has different attribute names. That's why I preferred to store metrics in a text file and append that file to database, sir.

Comment: Do whatever you want, but introducing a file is not the best solution for your problem

Comment: ok sir, now I tried to add metrics' attributes directly into database and done it. But I want to know whether adding a metrics file to database of any server is not good for security reason or is there any other drawbacks on doing this, sir? Just want to learn what is the drawback because I will not make that in future.